# Which tool for colorizing output of javac?

Tags: java, colors, terminal, javac

We have a hugely parallelized build process, so I frequently have to browse through large amounts of output from javac to find a build error.

To make this easier it would be nice if there were some tool that will colorize the output of javac to my terminal, highlighting errors in the code.

**What tool can I use to colorize the output of javac?**

Comment: My best solution so far is to use generic colorizer tool (http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html), and write my own configuration for colorizing the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a tool called [Generic Colorizer Tool](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html) and write my own configuration for colorizing the most important output. Works just fine. :)

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem, is your config for grc available for a download somewhere?

Comment: No, basically I just needed to get error output highlighted, so I can find it among several thousands lines of compiler output, coming from 16 concurrent threads. :) So my filter is simply to color error-lines in read and make it bold. :)

Answer (score 1):

using **grep** with the "--color" option ?

```
~$ javac Test.java 2>&1 | egrep --color "^|error"
```

Comment: Except this will suppress all output that are not errors, which I do not want.

Comment: Feels a bit hackish just to add a high number to -A/-B? :)

Comment: grepping using `"^|error"` will print all lines, highlight on 'error' and will not use the hack to print 10 thousand lines.

Answer (score 0):

### Roll your own javac error colorizer by using any regex matcher to match your text and surround it with terminal color escape codes to apply a color:

Using a `readfile` and `substitute` ideology:

```
#1.  Do your javac and pipe the result to a file:
javac whatever.java 2>/tmp/javac_errors.out;

#define the escape start and stop codes that your terminal 
#uses to apply foreground and background color:
let redbackground        = '\\e[48;5;196m'
let normalbackground     = '\\e[0;0m'

#iterate the lines in the saved file:
for line in readfile("/tmp/javac_errors.out")

    #Use sed, match, substitute or whatever to regex substitute 
    #the text with the text surrounded by the color escape codes
    #find and replace the text 'error:' with the same surrounded by escape codes
    let line = substitute(line, 
                          'error:',
                           redbackground . 
                           'error:' . 
                           normalbackground, 'g')

    #use echo -e flag to tell the terminal to interpret the escape codes:
    echo -e line
endfor
```

### Works for me:

[image: javac colorzing example]

This code is the same as above, but it uses a terminal line iterator and a `sed` replace ideology:

```
#run javac pipe to file
javac whatever.java 2>/tmp/errors.out

#Define terminal color codes
redbackground='\\e[48;5;196m'
normalbackground='\\e[0;0m'

#read the file and print out each line 
filename="/tmp/errors.out" 
while read -r line; do  
    #replace error surround with escape codes 
    line=`sed "s/error:/${redbackground}error:${normalbackground}/g" <<<"$line"` 
    echo -e "$line" 
done < "$filename"
```