# How can I color the output from javac?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, javac

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702984/which-tool-for-colorizing-output-of-javac) asking this question 5 years ago. Just looking to see if there are any updated solutions.

I'd like to get output behavior from
[javac (warnings, errors, etc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHNCo.png)

similar to that from [gcc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug8CF.png)

Ideally, I'd love to get bolded/white code line locations, different colorings for error, warnings, maybe even colored output for 'symbol:' and 'location:' output.

Comment: You could pipe it's output to a file and use [BareTail](https://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) to view it.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702984/which-tool-for-colorizing-output-of-javac

Comment: @Abdul Thanks, that post was the one I was referring to above.

Comment: @petebutler Ah, okay.